# how to bypass java generics type checking

Tags: java, generics

I got a interface like this:

`public T evaluate(float fraction, T startValue, T endValue);`

the other code will treat every `T` type as an `Object`, and finally I'll get the return value, which is an `Object` class too.

What I want is to pass `startValue` and `endValue` as integer, but return a totally different instance (not an `Integer`). I'll force cast the return value to what I supposed.

What I've done is to replace the `T` with object, like this:

`public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue)`

but this failed, I thought if the interface defined like `? extends T` will work, but it's not. (Am I right?)

So is there any way I can bypass the generics type check?

Comment: `What I want is to pass startValue and endValue as interger` - Why not write `public whateverTypeYouWantToReturn evaluate(float fraction, int startValue, int endValue);`?

Comment: @Eran this is a interface that I can't modify. So I'm seeking for workaround.

Comment: This doesn’t make the slightest sense. First, you describe how you changed the interface method by replacing the type parameter with `Object`, then you tell us in the comment that you can’t modify the interface.

Comment: @Holger I didn't modify the interface, I just implement the interface and use `Object` to fit the `T` type.

Comment: Well, `T`’s bound is `Object`, it would work when implementing the raw interface, assuming that `T` is a type variable of the interface rather than the method. You see, too many assumptions. If you posted the interface, the implementation and the caller, it perhaps could be answered…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I wrote this answer a long time ago when I didn't know much. Please consider the other answers.**

I suppose you have an interface like `interface Name<T>{}`.
Why not just let `T` be `Integer` and then cast what is returned to whatever you want. (if I wanted to get a string):

```
//interfaceInstance is Name<Integer>
//fraction is float, startValue and endValue are Integer
String value = String.valueOf(interfaceInstance.evaluate(fraction, startValue endValue))
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the way I'm going to do, I'm asking this because there's a kind of code format I have to followed, I want the code looks as the same as it usually to be, but any way, if there's not other choices, I'll get the return value and deal with it in other place.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your interface has a T generic parameter, add a second type, say R:

```
interface MyInterface<T,R> {
    public R evaluate(float fraction, T startValue, T endValue);
}
```

Comment: @reavenisadesk alright then, use it with Object and do the conversions yourself.

Comment: I'v tried to use all type as Object, but the force cast failed in runtime, it considered the return value is a Int type

Comment: I don't know what you are doing inside the `evaluate` method but because the presence of `float fraction` you should use this this approach, i.e. different types for input and output.